# How can I delete MySQL tables if i unchecked a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table with MySQL datas. Each data has an edit button. If I click one of the button, a bootstrap modal appears with the current datas of the selected row. In the modal I have a checkbox also. If I click on it, some input fields appear where I can update or insert datas in database. If the current row has datas, the hidden fields already appears when I click on the edit button. And I want to delete the datas If I unchecked the checkbox. I'm trying to put `if(!isset($_POST["licensee"]))` into the PHP file, but it didn't do anything. How can I solve this?

### index.php

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="companyModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <form method="post" id="company_form">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <b>Licensees </b><input type="checkbox" name="licensee" id="licensee"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hidden" class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                    <input class="action" type="hidden" name="company_id" id="company_id" />
                    <input class="action" type="hidden" name="btn_action" id="btn_action" />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-info action" value="Add" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      // Hide field if unchecked, show if checked
        $('[name=licensee]').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#hidden").show();
                $("#name").attr("required", true);
            } else {
                $("#hidden").hide();
                $("#name").attr("required", false);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.update', function() {
            var company_id = $(this).attr("id");
            var btn_action = 'fetch_single';
            $.ajax({
                url:"company.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{company_id:company_id, btn_action:btn_action},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('#companyModal').modal('show');
                    $('#company_id').val(company_id);;
                    $('#btn_action').val('Edit');

                    // Check if input empty
                    var name = jQuery.trim($("#name").val());
                    if(name.length > 0) {
                        $('#licensee').prop('checked', true);
                        $("#hidden").show();
                    } else if(name.length === 0){
                        $("#hidden").hide();
                        $('#licensee').prop('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
   )};
</script>
```

### company.php

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_action'])) {
    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'Add') {
        // Insert on Add
    }

    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'fetch_single') {
        // Fetch the company's current data on Edit
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    if($_POST['btn_action'] == 'Edit') {
        // Update on Edit
    } 
}

// It's didn't work
if(!isset($_POST['licensee'])) {
    echo '<script> alert("Success"); </script>';
}
```

Comment: What part of your code is working? Are you able to get the value of the checkbox to the php script with your ajax call?

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST['licensee']))` in this `licensee` is set, but its value will be 0. You can check that.

Answer (score 1):

**isset()** returns TRUE when a variable exists even if the value it holds is empty.

you can use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="licensee" id="licensee" value="value1"/>
```

and in PHP (if checkbox is checked):

```
if ($_POST['licensee'] == 'value1'){}
```